# QueryPerformanceCounter limiting/speeding up slide speed

Tags: c++

I have a thread that waits on a std::condition_variable then loops till it is done.

Im trying to slide my rect that is drawn in opengl.

Everything works fine without using a delta, But i would like my rect to slide at the same speed no matter what computer it is ran on.

At the moment it jumps about half way then slides really slow.

If i dont use my delta it does not run at the same speed if ran on slower computers.

Im not sure if i should ihave a if statement and check if time has passed then do the sliding, an not use a delta?

```
    auto toolbarGL::Slide() -> void
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER then, now, freq;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&then);

        while (true)
        {
            // Waits to be ready to slide
            // Keeps looping till stopped then starts to wait again
            SlideEvent.wait();

            QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
            float delta_time_sec = (float)(now.QuadPart - then.QuadPart) / freq.QuadPart;

            if (slideDir == SlideFlag::Right)
            {
                if (this->x < 0)
                {
                    this->x += 10 * delta_time_sec;
                    this->controller->Paint();
                }
                else
                    SlideEvent.stop();
            }
            else if (slideDir == SlideFlag::Left)
            {
                if (this->x > -90)
                {
                    this->x -= 10 * delta_time_sec;
                    this->controller->Paint();
                }
                else
                    SlideEvent.stop();
            }
            else
                SlideEvent.stop();

            then = now;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your rectangle to move at a steady speed no matter what, I suggest a different approach -- instead of relying on your code executing at a particular time and causing a side effect (like `x += 10`) each time, come up with a function that will tell you what the rectangle's location should be *at any given time*.  That way, no matter when your `Paint()` method is called, it will always draw the rectangle at the location that corresponds to that time.

For example:

```
// Returns the current time, in microseconds-since-some-arbitrary-time-zero
unsigned long long GetCurrentTimeMicroseconds()
{
   static unsigned long long _ticksPerSecond = 0;
   if (_ticksPerSecond == 0) _ticksPerSecond = (QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tps)) ? tps.QuadPart : 0;

   LARGE_INTEGER curTicks;
   if ((_ticksPerSecond > 0)&&(QueryPerformanceCounter(&curTicks)))
   {
      return (curTicks.QuadPart*1000000)/_ticksPerSecond;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("GetCurrentTimeMicroseconds() failed, oh dear\n");
      return 0;
   }
}

[...]

// A particular location on the screen
int startPositionX = 0;

// A clock-value at which the rectangle was known to be at that location
unsigned long long timeStampAtStartPosition = GetCurrentTimeInMicroseconds();

// The rectangle's current velocity, in pixels-per-second
int speedInPixelsPerSecond = 10;

// Given any clock-value (in microseconds), returns the expected position of the rectangle at that time
int GetXAtTime(unsigned long long currentTimeInMicroseconds)
{
   const long long timeSinceMicroseconds = currentTimeInMicroseconds-timeStampAtStartPosition;
   return startPositionX + ((speedInPixelsPerSecond*timeSinceMicroseconds)/1000000);
}

void PaintScene()
{
   const int rectX = GetXAtTime(GetCurrentTimeMicroseconds());

   // code to paint the rectangle at position (rectX) goes here...
}
```

Given the above, your program can call `PaintScene()` as seldom or as often as it wants, and your rectangle's on-screen speed will not change (although the animation will look more or less smooth, depending on how often you call it).

Then if you want the rectangle to change its direction of motion, you can just do something like this:

```
const unsigned long long now = GetCurrentTimeInMicroseconds();
startPositionX = GetXAtTime(now);
speedInPixelsPerSecond = -speedInPixelsPerSecond;  // reverse course!
```

The above example uses a simple `y=mx+b`-style equation that provides linear motion, but you can get many different types of motion, by using different [parametric equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) that take a time-value argument and return a corresponding position-value.

Comment: for some reason, the more times i getmy rect to move with this the faster it gets